# Gradle: how to remove main sourceSet from test dependencies?

Tags: gradle

```
src/main
src/test
```

Gradle testJar

```
> Task : compileJava
> Task : processResources
> Task : classes 
> Task : compileTestJava
> Task : processTestResources
> Task : testClasses
> Task : testJar
```

Test code is selenium code which does not have dependencies on main source set. But building test jar will always compile main source set. How to remove the dependencies on main?